# 4x PCI-E interface w/SSD

Tags: pci-express, pagefile

Windows Server 2003 64bit/32GB Ram/78GB HDD

I would like to store my server page files on a PCIe SSD in the 4xPCIe slot on my server. The server is a transaction server with high memory requirement and I've noticed the server is paging to disk occasionally.

If when I  install the PCIe, can I use that full amount of space and use it the fast page file drive.

Comment: Worth reviewing: [Latency Numbers...](https://gist.github.com/jboner/2841832).

Comment: Great link really I've loads of questions, how do I find out more about latency.

Comment: You dig into documentation. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you do that? Memory is cheaper - just buy more memory?

Anyway, if you insist then so long as your PCIe SSD acts as an AHCI device then it will be available at boot time and could be selected as a swap drive yes - some don't let you do this, basically if it lets you boot from it you'll be fine, if you need drivers then you may very well not be able to.

Comment: The server in question cannot be upgraded past 32gb so rather than purchase and build another server adding the PCIe SSD might be an option to improve performance.

Comment: @JJJJNR If your server is limited to 32GB RAM, that implies that it's of an older generation (CPU/system board/bus speeds). You may get a better performance boost and longer lifetime by going to a newer system that can accommodate your RAM needs, etc. If not, you *could* use an SSD device, but it's no substitute for RAM.

Comment: I'm thinking about that, and its prob going to be the best option. The service running on this server is only paging occasionally, but its a speed dependent application so the DEV team don't want any writes to page file only in emergency, which is pretty much whats happening, would ditching 2003 server and upgrading to 2008 R2 improve the overall performance.